# How to display mathematical formula ckeditor in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, editor

I'm using ckeditor with math formula to display on my web page, I want to it just display formula within table. However when I run it can not display math formula

this is my source:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({   tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]} }); </script>

</head>

<body>
<script>
 function mExamArea()
 {
  var strArea = "";
  var i = 0;

strArea += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='left' valign='top' width='100%' id='contents2'>";
for(var k = ArrStart[gindex - 1] - 1; k < ArrEnd[gindex - 1]; k++)
{
    i++;
    strArea += "<tr><td>";
    strArea += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='left' valign='top' width='100%'>";
    strArea += "<tr><td height='20'></td></tr><tr><td>";

    if (ArridRef[k] != "0")
    {
        strArea += "<div id='ref'></div>";
        strArea += "</td></tr>";
        strArea += "<tr><td height='12'></td></tr><tr><td>";
    }

    strArea += "<table border='3' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='left' valign='top'>";
    strArea += "<tr>";
    strArea += "<div class='math-tex'><td width='20' valign='top' style='line-height:2.1'><div id='quizno" + i + "'></div></td></div>";
    strArea += "<td width='5'></td>";
    strArea += "<div class='math-tex'><td style='line-height:2.1'><H1><div id='quiz" + i + "'></div></H1></td></div>";
    strArea += "</tr>";
    strArea += "</table></td></tr>";
    strArea += "<tr><td height='7'></td></tr><tr><td>";

    strArea += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='left' valign='top'>";
    strArea += "</table></td></tr></table></td></tr>";
}

strArea += "</table></td></tr></table>";

document.all.quizdiv.innerHTML = strArea;
}
</script>

<div style="overflow: auto; height: 700; width: 100%" id="centerdiv">
            <div id="quizdiv" style="width: 100%;"></div>
            <div id="msg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
            <div><br>&nbsp;<br></div>       
            <div id="button" style="width: 100%;">
                <a href="javascript:PreviousQ();" class="btn_m" id="prevbtn">Previous</a> <a href="javascript:NextQ();" class="btn_m" id="nextbtn">Next</a>
                 <a title="Answer submission" class="btn_pop btn_navy" href="javascript:SubmitPage();" id="examsubmit">Answer submission</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

within value of i is:

```
\(x = {-b pm sqrt{b^2-4ac} over 2a}\)
```

value of this param I get from database..

How to display math formula in web page? Thank so much !!

Answer (score -2):

use the MathJax is an open-source JavaScript display engine for LaTeX, MathML, and AsciiMath notation that works in all modern browsers. See the below code.

```
   <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({   tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]} }); </script>

    <p>\(x = {-b pm sqrt{b^2-4ac} over 2a}\) </p>
```

For more detail read the documentation of mathjax.
https://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: thanks for your answer, however value of i will display on table within javascript, is not html...

Comment: I have try with: <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({   tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]} }); </script> but not display ..